# How do I convert a masked textbox to an int with the mask of 000-000?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, maskedtextbox

```
int AccNo = Convert.ToInt32(AccMaskedTextBox.Text);
```

This is how I try to assign the input of my maskedtextbox. The issue I have is that I set a custom mask. It is in the form of 000-000. When I try to assign the input of maskedtextbox to AccNo it breaks with the error :

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

The value of AccNo comes out to be for example 123-456 if string type is used. So I need to get rid of the hyphen so I can assign it to type int.
How can I do t without changing my mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be using [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) to replace the hyphen with nothing:

```
int AccNo = Convert.ToInt32(AccMaskedTextBox.Text).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Thanks! It was such an easy but a handy way! :)

Comment: fastest answer i have ever seen

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary must have refreshed as it was posted. shrug.

Comment: @Kadir did this solve your issue? If it did, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.